# Why is my register function not working in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

Very new Python programmer here, literally my first OOP project. I made a bank account. Bold, I know. Here is my code so far:

```
    def __init__(self, balance, username, password):
        """ Making the actual bank account :) """
        self.money = balance

    def registerUsername(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.username = input("What is your username? ")

    def registerPassword(self, password):
        self.password = password
        self.password = input("What is your password? ")

    def login(self, attemptedUsername, attemptedPassword):
        self.attemptedUsername = attemptedUsername
        self.attemptedPassword = attemptedPassword
        if self.attemptedUsername == self.username and self.attemptedPassword == self.password:
            print("Success! You have been logged in! ")
        elif self.attemptedUsername != self.username and self.attemptedPassword != self.password:
            print('None of the fields entered are correct. Please try again! ')
        elif self.attemptedUsername == self.username and self.attemptedPassword != self.password:
            print("Your password is incorrect. Please try again! ")
        elif self.attemptedUsername != self.username and self.attemptedPassword == self.password:
            print("Your username is incorrect. Please try again! ")

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """ Deposit money using this function! """
        self.money += amount
        return self.money

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """ Withdraw money using this method! """
        self.money -= amount
        return self.money

    def getbalance(self):
        """ Returns the amount of money you have in your account """
        return self.money
```

So, my register function keeps breaking. Both the password and the username. WHen I use it, It requires me to write a `Self: BankAccount` parameter, before writing my user and password. Please help!

EDITED:

here is my issue. I have attached a picture.[please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NjjG.png)

As you can see, it makes me input a self parameter, before I can write my actual username. I don't want to input any paraments before username, is there a way to eliminate the self?

Comment: forgot to mention, I found this code online. Just making some tweaks!

Comment: "Bold, I know" - no there's nothing bold. You can remove that line, it doesn't contribute anything to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both registerUsername and registerPassword look like they ask for the username and password twice. There are many ways to interpret the code and what is trying to do. If you post more of the question, then I can help you further.

EDIT:
Thanks for uploading the image of your attempt.

The last line in your image, replace with:

```
account = BankAccount(1000, 'Adam', 'Password')
```

This will call the `__init__` function and create a bank account with $1000, with a username of Adam, and a password of Password. Next, add the following lines:

```
account.withdraw(250)
print(account.getbalance())
```

This will take 250 from the balance, then print the current balance of the account, now $750.

What we have done is created a BankAccount object and stored it into the `account` variable. If we want to create another BankAccount object we can, and the two accounts will be seperate. For example:

```
account_one = BankAccount(1000, 'Adam', 'Password')
account_two = BankAccount(1000, 'Ben', 'AnotherPassword')

account_one.withdraw(250)
print(account_one.getbalance())

account_two.deposit(500)
print(account_two.getbalance())

# Account One has $750. Account Two has $1500
```

Hope this helps. Keep it up.

Comment: I don't have a homework question, its a self learning type thing. Do you have Discord perhaps? We could connect there. I don't understand what you mean 